# Changing the case of lines in ed

Tags: case, ed

Can I employ the `tr` command to change the case of a line or range of lines while working in `ed`? Or is there another way?

Comment: Doing filtering through external utilities is not really convinient unless you filter the whole editing buffer.  Another thing that is unreasonably difficult is to run something like `par` or `fmt` on a set of lines.

Comment: Okay. That's helpful. In sam one can use |tr a-z A-Z to change dot.

Comment: Another alternative is to use `sed` which has the `tr`-equivalent transliteration operator `y` built-in.  e.g. `printf '%s\n' {01..10} | sed -e '1,5y/0/x/'` will change the `0` characters to `x` on lines 1-5 only.  sed's `-i` option allows it to do in-place edits of existing files.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering a range of lines through some external utility in `ed` is not easy. You will have to do this as a set of at least three commands and use a temporary file.

Let's say our external filter is called `utility` and that we want to filter the lines from 20 to 30 through that filter.

The lines that we want to filter are addressed with `20,30`. We'll start by writing these lines to our filter, saving the output to a file called `tmp` (an arbitrary name):

```
20,30 w !utility >tmp
```

We may then replace the lines in the buffer with those from the resulting output file:

```
20,30 d
20- r tmp
```

This will first delete the lines filtered through `utility` and then insert the resulting data after line 20 (`20-` is the same as `19`, and the `r` command inserts the text from the named file *after* the addressed line).

This could possibly be made neater by using `ed` together with `rlwrap` and coming up with some sort of Readline macro that you could more easily execute, but I'm not the person to look into that.  Changing one's editor to something like `ex` would likely be a more realistic approach if you want to do text editing that requires the use of external filters, and want to use a line editor for doing so.